# Firebase Notification : Should always ring even if the phone is in silent/DND/vibrate mode

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I have created an android application and would like to notify using firebase. But I want to make the phone ring always even it is in silent/vibrate/dnd mode.

The below code I have written is not working in some scenarios' like if someone does lower the alarm volume/ and in some phones not working with silent mode.

This is my FirebaseMessageReceiver.java file

```
public class FirebaseMessageReceiver extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        Log.d(TAG, "myFirebaseMessagingService - onMessageReceived - message: " + remoteMessage);
        Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        dialogIntent.putExtra("msg", remoteMessage);
        startActivity(dialogIntent);

    }

    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification, Map<String, String> data) {
        String channel_id = getString(default_notification_channel_id);
        String channel_name = getString(default_notification_channel_name);
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        Uri notification_sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.alert);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
        intent.putExtra("message", notification.getBody());
        intent.putExtra("title", notification.getTitle());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Log.d(TAG, "Alert Sound  Value" + notification_sound);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channel_id)
                .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                .setContentText(notification.getBody())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(notification_sound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentInfo(notification.getTitle())
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setColor(Color.RED)
                .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                .setShowWhen(true)
//                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);


        try {
            String picture_url = data.get("picture_url");
            if (picture_url != null && !"".equals(picture_url)) {
                URL url = new URL(picture_url);
                Bitmap bigPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(
                        new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bigPicture).setSummaryText(notification.getBody())
                );
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            setupChannels(notificationManager);
        }
            notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
            startActivity(intent);

    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void setupChannels(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
        String adminChannelName = getString(default_notification_channel_name);
        String adminChannelDescription = getString(default_notification_channel_name);
        String channelid = getString(default_notification_channel_id);
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        Uri notification_sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.i_phone_mix);

        NotificationChannel adminChannel;
        adminChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelid, adminChannelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        adminChannel.setDescription(adminChannelDescription);
        adminChannel.enableLights(true);
        adminChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        adminChannel.enableVibration(true);
        adminChannel.canBypassDnd();
        Log.d(TAG, "Alert Sound  Value" + notification_sound);
        AudioAttributes audio_attribute = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                .build();
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,
                audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM),
                0);
        adminChannel.setSound(notification_sound, audio_attribute);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(adminChannel);
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want ring bell on device.Any situation if the phone is silent mode Dns mode/vibration mode and mobile display is off so you can follow this code.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public static final String FCM_PARAM = "picture";
    private static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "FCM";
    private static final String CHANNEL_DESC = "Firebase Cloud Messaging";
    private int numMessages = 0;



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.notification_speech);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
        sendNotification(notification, data);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage.Notification notification, Map<String, String> data) {

        Log.d("notification_", String.valueOf(notification));
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        // bundle.putString(FCM_PARAM, data.get(FCM_PARAM));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("notificationValue", String.valueOf(data));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
                .setContentText(notification.getBody())
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setContentInfo("Hello").setSound(null)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nofi_icon))
                .setLights(Color.RED, 1000, 300)
                .setNumber(++numMessages).setSound(null)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.nofi_icon);

        try {
            String picture = data.get(FCM_PARAM);
            if (picture != null && !"".equals(picture)) {
                URL url = new URL(picture);
                Bitmap bigPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                notificationBuilder.setStyle(
                        new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bigPicture).setSummaryText(notification.getBody())
                );
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    getString(R.string.app_name), CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            );

            channel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESC);
            channel.setShowBadge(true);
            channel.canShowBadge();
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            channel.setSound(null, null);

            AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100, 0);

            channel.enableVibration(true);
            //channel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
            channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500});


            assert notificationManager != null;
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Prem, Thank you so much but is that code work with only when the application is in background?

Comment: When application background it's working good  when you have define proper services in manifest like this:    <service android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
                <action android:name="co.example.yourApp.ui.notifications_TARGET_NOTIFICATION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>